# I'm trying to build a simple webscraper and keep getting this SSL error:

Tags: python-3.x

*This is my code:*

```
import requests
from requests import get
from requests.exceptions import RequestException
from contextlib import closing
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import ssl
from time import sleep

url = 'https://techcrunch.com/'
response = requests.get(url, timeout=5)
content = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")

print(content)
```

When I run this it returns this error:

> Error Traceback (most recent call last)

...

> SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='techcrunch.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])")))

Comment: Try setting a bigger timeout, like 500.

Comment: Tried it and I keep getting the same error